# Speech to text audiofile limit request

Tags: google-cloud-speech

Our company using speech to text API for making searchable audiobooks. Some of our audio files reach 20 hours, but as we noticed, the basic limit for using Speech to text is 480 minutes.

Please let me know how can we request to enlarge our limit to 1200 minutes?

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts.  You can say thanks to the author of the answer below by either upvoting the post, or accepting it (as you've already done), but don't remove the content of your question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [Stack Overflow cannot answer customer support questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745). Please consider contacting customer support for the company in question with your issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can request a higher limit from Google. The process is described [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota#requesting_higher_quota), and there is an interactive guide [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?tutorial=cloud_quota_request).

> To request a higher quota limit by using the Google Cloud Console:
>
> 1. Go to the **Quotas** page:
> 2. On the **Quotas** page, find the quota you want to increase in the **Limit name** column.
>
>    You can use the **Filter** search box to search for your quota.
> 3. Select the checkbox to the left of your quota.
> 4. Click **EDIT QUOTAS**. The **Quota changes** form displays.
> 5. In the **Quota changes** form, enter the increased quota that you want for your project in the **New limit** field.
> 6. Complete any additional fields in the form, and then click **DONE**.
> 7. Click **SUBMIT REQUEST**.
>
> While the above procedure applies to most quota increase requests, you
> might encounter one of the following exceptions:
>
> - In some cases, the Google Cloud Console redirects you to a separate form to request an increased limit. After you submit the
>   form, Google Cloud acknowledges your request by email.
> - Some quotas cannot be updated using the Google Cloud Console. If you find that you cannot change a quota from the console, request the increase from [Cloud Customer Care](https://cloud.google.com/support). The Billing team does not handle quota limit increases.